# Serialization detection?

Tags: java, serializable

```
class MyClass implements Serializable{}
```

What must I write so that the Object knows when it is getting serialized and deserialized to do something before getting serialized and after getting deserialized?

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve? Serialized objects maintain their state when being written out to a .ser file.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific about what is your ultimate goal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `readObject` and `writeObject` methods for this purpose. `writeObject` method will be executed when serializing your object reference.

Basically, you will do it like this:

```
public class MyClassToSerialize implements Serializable {
    private int data;
    /* ... methods ... */
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os) throws IOException {
        os.defaultWrite(); //serialization of the current serializable fields
        //add behavior here
    }
}
```

More info on the usage of these methods: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html)

Comment: That methods are from ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream. Classes for serializing and deserializing objects. But the object itself can0t detect if it's going to be serialized or deserialized.

Comment: @eyp `writeObject` is called when the object is being serialized. Isn't that a *way* to detect that I am about to be serialized (in case I am an object reference and my class implements `Serializable`)?

Comment: Serializable.writeObject is a private method, so you can't override it to change its behavior.

Comment: @eyp that method is not part of `Serializable`. Interfaces cannot have `private` methods, all the methods of an interface are by default `public abstract`. You need to review some Java.

Comment: `writeObject` and `readObject` are totally weird beasts: private callback methods that are never invoked from your own code. Not one of Java's better design choices.

Comment: @Arend yeah, but that's how it is =\.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I know. Your answer is quite correct. Just giving my opinion about this feature of Java.

Comment: @Arend I know that, sorry if my comments look rude or serious. There are other parts of the design of Java that I don't like that much like this one, but we can only use it if needed. Some day another programming language running on the JVM will arise after learning the lessons from design flaws made in Java and others. Not pointing to a specific programming language though.